# Function calling messed event handling

Tags: javascript, html, function, event-handling, this

I trigger the event (focus the input element) only after the eventhandle() produces output after the body load. The comments are the output that are produced when eventhandle is called by the event Firing.

```
<input type="text" value="xyz" ></input>
<script>
    eventhandle();
    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].onclick=eventhandle
    function eventhandle()
    {
        alert(this.value);//works
        alert(event);    //works
        alert(event.type)//Error for all the properties of event object
    }
</script>
```

This problem gets resolved if I call eventhandle() after the DOM fires event on target ie.

```
<input type="text" value="xyz" ></input>
<script>
    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].onclick=eventhandle
    function eventhandle()
    {
        alert(this.value);
        alert(event.type); //works for all properties of event object
        alert(event)       //works
    }
    eventhandle();
</script>
```

I cant understand why the error occurs and how it gets resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I don't know why you call the eventhandle like that, I mean `eventhandle()`? An event handle is not for calling directly, it will be called after an event is fired.

Secondly, you got the error because when the eventhandle function was called, your page was not completely loaded. You should use window.onload = your_handler first

Comment: I called eventhandle() to test if the javascript interprets the event handler function before the execution of javascript begins just like any other function declaration.I fount javascript interprets the function even before event was triggered.

Comment: I think your event handler declaration should be: `function eventhandle(event){// do something with your event.}`

Comment: please remove the function call, I think that was called first so you encounter the error.

Comment: tahts what is my Question about WHY that??

Comment: There is a global object named: event. But its "type" property is not defined, this property only defined when an event is actually fired. You called the function first even before any event was fired so ERROR!

Comment: Sir please for my sake do one thing copy paste the code and run it.Then focus the input Element after all manual alert have popped up

Comment: @Rikky-Only you are active onto this Post SO you are my last hope.Plz do it

Answer (score 1):

> I cant understand why the error occurs

At the moment you are calling `eventhandle()` manually, no event was triggered, so the global `event` variable does not have a value.

> and how it gets resolved

As you can see here, placing the call at the end of the code, doesn't actually resolve the error: http://jsfiddle.net/M7rXK/. The problem is still the same.

Comment: @chetanmehta: The global variable `event` always exist (in IE and Chrome at least), but it doesn't have a value when no event was triggered.

Comment: What is it that you still don't understand? `window.event` only has a value when an actual event was triggered. You are calling `eventhandle` "manually", i.e. *not* in response of an event, hence `window.event` is `undefined`.

Comment: Ok with your event object description but errors not occur when eventhandle() is called manually but when event triggers.

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/M7rXK/1/. However it won't work in Firefox since the `event` object is passed as argument to the handler, it is not global. To make it work in FF, use `function eventhandle(event) { event = event || window.event; ... }`. Have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is my code:

```
<input type="text" value="xyz" ></input>
<script>
    // eventhandle(); I hate this, verymuch =="
    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].onclick=eventhandle
    function eventhandle(event) // please parse a parameter represent the event here
    {
        alert(this.value);//works
        alert(event);    //works
        alert(event.type)// If works, plz tell me :D
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not experience with browser compatible, may be you declare the handle first, then bind the handle. Or if you have some other solution, plz tell me

Comment: @ricky-for Ie8  use AttachEvent

Comment: eventhandle() is called manually to check if the javascript engine interprets the event handler function even before the code execution starts just like any other function declaration

Answer (score 1):

Event doesn't exits in Firefox. The following code should work in most browsers though:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].onclick=eventhandle
function eventhandle(e)
{
    var event = e || window.event;
    console.log(this.value); // works
    console.log(event.type); //works for all properties of event object
    console.log(event)       //works
}
// trigger the click event without actually clicking on it
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].click();
```

In IE you have to press F12 to open the developer tools to see the console.log or it'll generate an error. In most other browsers you have to press F12 as well to open the console and see the console messages but it won't generate an error if it's not open.